# $scope assignment isn't working - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my code I am creating a reset button to wipe a form clean. with the reset I also want a value that's dependent on that input to also clear. Within the reset() function, $scope.funding.startingEstimate is correctly set to zero, however $scope.funding.needed is not. Furthermore, shouldn't the $watch scope function take care of that already? Anytime the funding.startEstimate is changed (as it is successfully in the $scope.reset function, shouldn't the recommended field also return to zero because the $watch function calls computeNeeded which multiplies funding.startingEstimate by 10 (with 0*10 equaling 0).

Please help.

Below is my code:

app.js

```
app.controller('StartUpController',["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.funding = {startingEstimate:0};


    $scope.computeNeeded=function(){
        console.log("test2")
        $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
    };

    $scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', $scope.computeNeeded);

    $scope.requestFunding=function(){
        window.alert("Sorry, please get more customers first");
    };

    $scope.reset=function(){
        console.log("test")
        $scope.funding.startingEstimate = 0;
        $scope.funding.needed = 0;

    };


}]);

<form ng-controller="StartUpController" ng-submit="requestFunding()" ng-reset="reset()">
            Starting: <input ng-model="funding.startingEstimate" > 
            Recommendation:{{funding.needed}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Request Funding </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" >Reset</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll kick yourself when I tell that you neglected to invoke the `reset()` method in Angular – instead you defined the button's `type` as `reset` so you were getting the basic HTML functionality of resetting a form.

I've added the `ng-click` for you: http://jsfiddle.net/z8edmpp2/

Comment: To add to your answer, I dont believe there exist an Angular directive called ng-reset, so that should be removed altogether.

Comment: Agreed. I've never seen a `ng-reset` directive.